# Can I control mouse properties like click speed?

Tags: c++, windows, mouse, system, std

can I change some mouse properties like double click speed in:

```
system("control mouse");
```

Comment: not nativelly that I know of, but you can use the underlying API(Windows or Linux); I have no experience in doing such things, so I can't give you any more insight

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are trying to do this by launching `control mouse` I assume you are using windows. You will be better off using the Windows API call [`SystemParametersInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724947%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and passing it `SPI_SETDOUBLECLICKTIME` to change the speed of the double click.

```
SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETDOUBLECLICKTIME, delayValueInMS, NULL, 0);
```